# Find the hours and minutes of a cycle in one day

Tags: javascript, function, time

For a mini project i need to find the next time of one cycle in one day.
we have a rotor that it is working 40 minutes and it is standby also for 40 minutes, if time of his start is 11:40, we should find all the next times of his starts in next 24 h by hours and minutes, like : 13:00, 14:20 etc.

```
const time = new time('11:40');

time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 40);


console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite case specific, but it can be easily made more generic.
First, you can easily work with dates in VanillaJS using the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

We can deduce the rotor starts every 80 minutes, so the proposed solution adds 80 minutes to the start Date at every iteration.

```js
const minuteInterval = 40 * 2;
const minutesPerDay = 24 * 60;
const intervals = Math.floor(minutesPerDay / minuteInterval);

let moment = new Date('2022-12-28T11:40:00.000Z');
for (let i = 0; i < intervals; i++) {
    moment = new Date(moment.getTime() + minuteInterval * 60000);
    console.log(moment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Heyman, that finally worked with your suggestion code, I appreciate.